# Linux/gcc - How should I compile my programs to use libraries installed in my home directory?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

I never programmed in a computer without access to install libraries as root so I'm not really sure of what should I do to use libraries that I do not install in the usual places.

Usually, when I have admin priviledges I'd do the usual:

```
./configure 
make 
make install
```

to install the library. Then I'd do the common `#include <library>` and compile with (actually this is done in my makefile):

```
gcc -c file1.c
   gcc -c file2.c
   ...
   gcc file1.o file2.o ... -o executable -llibrary
```

How should I deal with a library that was installed in my home folder? Suppose I install it with:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make 
make install
```

And now I have directories like `$HOME/include`, `$HOME/lib` and `$HOME/share`, etc... how should I include the lib, compile and link the binaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
-L/home/yours/subdirforlibs
```

to the linker's command line to instruct it to look in that directory for libraries.

The directory options for gcc are explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)